# python requests send string as file

Tags: python, python-requests

In my code I am currently chunking up a file and sending reading it into a temporary file, then passing this temporary file into requests. Is there a way to still send this

```
with open(full_path, 'r+b') as f:
  i=0
  while True:
  chunk = f.read(max_chunk_size)
  if not chunk:
    break
  with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as t:
    t.write(chunk)
    t.seek(0)
    r = requests.post(endpoint + 'upload_chunk',
                      files={'chunk':t},
                      data={'mod_time':file_update_time,
                            'directory':'/'.join(subdirs),
                            'filename':filename,
                            'chunk_pos':i},
                      auth=auth)
    i+=max_chunk_size
```

Is there a way to send the chunk to the server without writing it to a temporary file, then having something in requests.post read this file? I'd much prefer to not have to change the server-side code. I'd imagine not having to read/write an extra 4 megabytes would increase execution speed.

Chunking up the file is necessary; this code is not yet complete.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have a read through the Requests [Quickstart page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart), under the [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) section.

There you'll find this:

> If you want, you can send strings to be received as files:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': ('report.csv', 'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
>>> r.text
{
  ...
  "files": {
    "file": "some,data,to,send\\nanother,row,to,send\\n"
  },
  ...
}
```

Note that `"file"` is the name of the file upload field the server is expecting. It would correspond to the following HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

Comment: This worked for me except be sure to change `file` to the variable name your server is looking for.

Comment: @Bijan I added a note based on your feedback.

Comment: Thanks @JonathonReinhart, I know this is an old answer but it would help save future users problems :)

Comment: @Bijan Absolutely. Stack Overflow is *meant* to serve as a reference, so there's never an answer too old to be improved.